# Apply Conditions To Both Child and Grandchild in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables and I want to be able to fetch the records where the Feature `value_number` is `2` and the Field `show_list` is `1`

```
Products
|------|
|  id  |
|------|
|   1  |

Features
|------|--------------|-------------|
|  id  |   value_num  |   field_id  |        
|------|--------------|-------------|
|   1  |       2      |     1       |
|------|--------------|-------------|
|   2  |       3      |     2       |

Fields
|------|---------------|
|  id  |  show_list    |
|------|---------------|
|   1  |      1        |
|------|---------------|
|   2  |      0        |
```

My Models looks like:

Products

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

Features

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feature extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class);
    }

    public function field()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Field::class);
    }
}
```

Fields

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Field extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

The farthest I've got with my query is:

```
    $category = $category->load(['products' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['features' => function ($query) {
            $query->join('fields', 'features.field_id', '=', 'fields.id')
                ->with('field')
                ->where('show_list', 1)
                ->where('value_number', 2);
        }]);
    }]);
```

The following works but the query is horrendous, I'm sure that there must be a better way of doing it:

```
$category = $category->load(['products' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['features' => function ($x) {
        $x->with('field')
            ->whereHas('field', function($y) {
                $y->where('show_list', 1);
            });
    }])
        ->whereHas('features', function ($query) {
            $query->where('value_number', 2);
        });}]);
```

Comment: Your query is quite complex, I don't think there's a better solution.

Comment: Do you worry about sql produced or because of php code.